# Why my flashing laser can't kill a player in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am a super beginner for Roblox programing.
I want to make a killing laser box with flashing.
my code is something like this.

```lua
local Laser = script.Parent

local function onPartTouch(otherPart)
    local touchObject = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = touchObject:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if (humanoid) then
        humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end

while true do
    Laser.Transparency = 1
    wait(1)
    Laser.Transparency = 0
    wait(1) 
end

Laser.Touched:Connect(onPartTouch)
```

In the case without flashing. that box worked. but once add the above `while` block then that box gets messed. that box doesn't work when touched.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably also set your Laser to be CanCollide = false. Otherwise, players might still be hitting the laser even when it is invisible.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a hint. I also needed to set my Laser to be Anchored = true. but even when CanCollide is disabled, my Laser still fire the Touched event. so it needed the touched part to pass through when its CanCollide is disabled.
This official document is super useful to me.
https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/property/BasePart/CanCollide

Answer (score 1):

```
while true do
    Laser.Transparency = 1
    wait(1)
    Laser.Transparency = 0
    wait(1) 
end
```

This is an infinite loop. Your script is executed, the interpreter enters that loop and never leaves it again. So the following line

```
Laser.Touched:Connect(onPartTouch)
```

will never be executed.

If you want to make something blink, consider using a timer.

Comment: They could just move the Laser.Touched line before the while loop. Since this script is a child of the laser, it might not be a big deal that it loops forever

Comment: You guys are right. I should have moved the `Laser.Touched` line before the while loop!!